# testing Django apps with project settings

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I am new to Django and trying to learn more about how certain apps are tested.  So this question is as much about django's testing philosophies as it is about a specific problem I've had.

I've begun using the [django-allauth app](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) to add oauth capabilities to my system.  Within my site, I've implemented a custom "whitelisting adapter" that rejects oauth attempts from email addresses not belonging to some set of domains.

The functionality works as expected on my site, but now the allauth tests fail when I run `python manage.py test google` (`allauth.socialaccount.providers.google` is a sub-app in allauth).  The allauth tests pass again if I disable my whitelisting adapater.  Why does my custom setup affect the tests of another app?  Shouldn't the allauth tests be more isolated to testing the internal allauth functionality and be less "end-to-end"?

And what is the most correct way to work around this (or fix it)?  Create a `test_settings.py` for use in testing that doesn't add custom functionality to allauth?  This too seems strange because I want to test my adapter in my own tests.

Comment: This is most likely an issue that needs to be raised on django-allauth's issue tracker.

Comment: @MarkR. I have recently raised the issue [here](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/843).  I guess I wanted to ask here as well because I'm not sure if this behavior (using project settings) is the norm for the tests of other django apps.

Comment: Having several sets of settings is definitely acceptable, especially if you're delving into automated testing/CI later on.

Comment: This might be useful: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-override-settings